# How to compare columns of a 2 different tables in Django views?

Tags: django

I have 2 tables Questions and Answers. 2 tables having answer column. I want to compare Questions table answer column with answers table answer column and show the result using session. Please guide me to solve this.

I saved my questions with answers and user answers into database.

```
def questions(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = QuestionsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'saved successfully')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('questions')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'not saved')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('questions')
    else:
        form = QuestionsForm()
    return render(request, 'questions.html', {'form':form})


def answer(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        question_ans = request.POST.get('answer', '')
        question = request.POST.get('question', '')
        print(f'ans: {question_ans}, ques: {question}', flush=True)
        ques = Questions.objects.get(question=question)
        if ques is not None:
            question_ans1 = Answer(answer=question_ans, question=ques)
            question_ans1.save()
            return render(request, 'answer.html')
        else:
            return render(request, 'report.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'report.html')


def result(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        user_ans = Answers.objects.get(answer=answer)
        ques_ans = Questions.objects.get(answer=answer)
        result = 0
        if ques_ans == user_ans:
            reslut +=1
        else:
            result -=0.33
        return render(request, 'result.html', {'result': result})
    else:
        return render(request, 'result.html')
```

model.py:

```
class Questions(models.Model):
        qs_no = models.IntegerField(default=None)
        question = models.TextField(max_length=500)
        option_a = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        option_b = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        option_c = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        option_d = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        ans = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=50)



class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Questions, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.answer
```

Comment: can you show your models here?

Comment: Hi  #Andrey Maslov. Posted my models. Thanks for your response.

Comment: show also how do you store results in your session

Comment: i don't know how to store with session. i saved to database using forms. Posted my code above please check it once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to count all answers for all questions you can do do it like this

```
def result(request):
    context = {}  
    if request.method=="POST":
        result = 0
        for answer in Answer.objects.all():
            if answer.answer == answer.question.ans:
                result += 1
            else:
                result -= 0.33
        context.update({
            'result': result,
        })
    return render(request, 'result.html', context)
```

or you can optimize it a little) making query like this

```
            for answer in Answer.objects.values("answer", "question__ans"):
                if answer["answer"] == answer["question__ans"]:
                    result += 1
                else:
                    result -= 0.33
```